# fastest way to get a pixel from a PyCDC image

Tags: python, image, winapi, screenshot, pixel

So I am trying to take a screenshot and get RGB values of around 50,000 pixel from it all in 0.02 seconds or less.
I have a screenshot that was captured using windows API and saved in a variable with type "PyCDC"
using this function:

```
def screenshot():
    width = 1920
    height = 1080

    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "chrome")
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(width, height) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # Free Resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    return cDC #returns the PyCDC image
```

And when I try to get RGB values for a certain pixel using:

```
def intToRGB(RGBint):
    b =  RGBint % 256
    g = (RGBint // 256) % 256
    r = (RGBint // 256 // 256) % 256
    return (r, g, b)

r, g, b = intToRGB(cDc.GetPixel(x, y))
```

it takes around 16x more time than getting RGB values for a pixel in a pyautogui image likes this:

```
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
img = screenshot.load()
r, g, b = img[x, y]
```

I tried giving a region for the pyautogui screenshot:

```
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(500, 500, 250, 250))
img = screenshot.load()
r, g, b = img[x, y]
```

But it seems to take the same amount of time as making it capture the whole screen.

I want to know if there is a way for me to convert the image to a normal python Image variable or perhaps get a pixel from the PyCDC image faster?

Comment: That will be difficult if you aren't experienced with GDI. Instead, find the geometry of the window and call ```pyautogui.screenshot()``` with the ```region``` option.